# TypeError: respuesta[0] is undefined

Tags: javascript

Qué tal?

Tengo este Código:

```html
$(".validarIdProducto").change(function(){

 $(".alert").remove();

 var idProducto = $(this).val();
 // console.log("​idProducto", idProducto)

 var datos = new FormData();
 datos.append("validarIdProducto", idProducto);

  $.ajax({
  url:app+"ajax/archivoencuestion.php",
  method:"POST",
  data: datos,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  dataType: "json",
  success:function(respuesta){

   if(respuesta[0]["id"].length != 0 && respuesta[0]["id_administrador"] != id_tienda){
    $(".validarIdProducto").parent().parent().after('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="mdi mdi-thumb-down-outline mr-1"></i>Esa publicación no es tuya sino de otro vendedor. Revisa el ID.</div>');
    $(".validarIdProducto").val("");

   }else if(respuesta[0]["id"].length != 0 && respuesta[0]["id_administrador"] == id_tienda){
    /* entonces está bien... */

   }

  }

 })

})
```

En otras palabras, lo que hago es traer de la base de datos un array.
Va de 10, lo trae y si encuentra coincidencia (si ese ID es encontrado en la base de datos) pero es de otro vendedor, me sale una alerta que dice que pertenece a otro vendedor. Si ese ID existe pero la publicacion es suya y no de otro, no ejecuta nada (else if) pero si ese ID ni siquiera existe, me sale:

> En Firefox Developer Edition: "TypeError: respuesta[0] is undefined".
>
> En Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of
>   undefined"

La respuesta que me tira es: `array(0) { }`

¿Cómo puedo hacer con un else if que me reconozca ese `array(0) { }` para entonces ejecutar una sentencia? Es decir, ¿cómo lo expreso?

Comment: que valor tiene respuesta, puedes agregar el JSON de retorno?

Answer (score 0):

Debes comprobar si existe respuesta[0]. He modificado tu código añadiendo una posibilidad de hacer dicha comprobación, pero hay muchas posibilidades de hacerlo.

```
$(".validarIdProducto").change(function(){

    $(".alert").remove();

    var idProducto = $(this).val();
    // console.log("​idProducto", idProducto)

    var datos = new FormData();
    datos.append("validarIdProducto", idProducto);

    $.ajax({
        url:app+"ajax/archivoencuestion.php",
        method:"POST",
        data: datos,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success:function(respuesta){
            if( typeof respuesta[0] != "undefined" ){ //Comprobando si existe respuesta[0], si existe hacemos esto....
                if(respuesta[0]["id"].length != 0 
                   && respuesta[0]["id_administrador"] != id_tienda){

                    $(".validarIdProducto").parent().parent().after(
                    '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                     <i class="mdi mdi-thumb-down-outline mr-1">
                     </i>Esa publicación no es tuya sino de otro vendedor. Revisa el 
                     ID. 
                     </div>');
                    $(".validarIdProducto").val("");

                }else if(respuesta[0]["id"].length != 0 &&
                     respuesta[0]["id_administrador"] == id_tienda){
                /* entonces está bien... */
                }

           }else{
                /* NO EXISTE EL ID */
           }

        }

   })

})
```

Comment: Probé esa forma pero me sale: ReferenceError: isset is not defined (eso que lo escribí bien). El json de retorno (si lo dejo como estaba) es: respuesta: [] length: 0 <prototype>: Array []

Comment: Efectivamente, acabo de corregir el código. Lo que añadí inicialmente era código PHP en vez de Javascript. Disculpad el error.